# HTML MVC Browser tool missing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Recently I noticed some kind of browser tool show at the bottom of my MVC app (after an update in Visual Studio), which had a HTML5 logo (the orange one) with a couple of options like Record CSS changes (I think to work out what is not used), and Auto-hide.

I hit the auto-hide and have no idea how to get the tool back, and I have no idea what this tool belongs to. It suspect it is related to Visual Studio web tools in some way but can't locate anything. It also reminded me of how Glimpse works.

Comment: I think if you have the browser active and you hit/hold shift the Visual Studio tools come up in the browser.

Comment: It's the CTRL key not shift, but thanks. Your suggestion made me try some other keys and I got lucky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit the CTRL key to make the menu visible.

There is a design and inspect mode, where it looks like changes to the page (in the browser) can be sync'ed back to Visual Studio.

Still not sure what tool or add-in this belongs to, but the Control key is what you can press to reshow the menu. The logo is an orange HTML looking logo with the Visual Studio logo on it in white.